# while element not found load ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page which contains long paginated content. Now for accessing one single item I want to load pages until I found desired item. Problem is my "while" loops always went into infinite loop. After some research I found that because of async behaviour of ajax it never finds element. here is the code I am working with

**While loop for loading content until element not found :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(document.getElementById('selectedItem')) {
        totalPages = $("#selectedItem").attr("totalPages");
        trgtElementUrl = $("#selectedItem").val();

        var targetElement = $("#" + trgtElementUrl);
        i = 2;

        //getting $('#'+trgtElementUrl).length always 0

        while(!($('#'+trgtElementUrl).length)) {
            $('#page' + i).trigger("click");
            i++;
        }

        target_top = $('#'+trgtElementUrl).offset().top;
        target_top = target_top - 10;

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500);

        $(".summaries li").removeClass();

        $('#'+trgtElementUrl).addClass('active');
    }

});
```

**And ajax call by triggering click event**

```
$('a.loadMore').live("click",function(event){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".loaderImage").show();
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {

            if($('a.loadMore').parent().parent().hasClass('advertisingGrid')){
                var items = $(data).find('ul.advertisingGridItems').html();
                $(items).hide().appendTo('ul.advertisingGridItems').show('normal');
            } else {
                var items = $(data).filter('ul.summaries').html();
                var subnav = $(data).filter('nav.subnav');
                var itemLinks = $(subnav).find('ul').html();
                $('div#pagination').remove();
                $(items).appendTo('ul.summaries');
                $(itemLinks).appendTo('.subnav ul');
            }

            $(".loaderImage").hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This always works fine with synchronous ajax call. Is it possible to make it work without synchronous ajax call. Thanks

Comment: What's synchronous about this call?

Comment: *This always works fine with synchronous ajax call. Is it possible to make it work without synchronous ajax call* ? -> **ajax** stands for **asynchronous** JavaScript and XML

Comment: No, because you'll be sending off thousands of ajax requests at the same time.

Comment: This is a bad way to search for an item. You should send the trgtElementUrl value in ONE ajax request and return the right page (containing the target item) from the server.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad explanation !! if i just put "async: false" in ajax call it works, but that may block my browsers UI untill all content loaded.

Comment: @intuitivepixel: Yes, but the jQuery.ajax supports sync calls (although not recommended and deprecated in some cases). That's probably what he/she was testing with.

Comment: @openbees: Yes, it works because it does block. But even then, this way of doing it is strange and bad. You could be generating many ajax requests just for the sake of reaching a target page. Why not send **one** ajax request with the name of the item you want and let the server return the exact page back to you?

Comment: @kevin-b any hack-a-round for this situation ?

Comment: @Ma3x Even I suggested same to my client but that idiot wants to display every element before that item.

Comment: @intuitivepixel thanks for definition dude :D

Comment: @openbees: Ok, can you clarify a bit? Does that mean that you want to animate the whole list until it reaches that item by showing all full pages in between?

Comment: @openbees Sure, re-structure your code so that you can properly perform an ajax request when needed.

Comment: @Ma3x, that's true - got your point

Comment: animation happens on last stage only, as you can see it will never go out of while unless element found. Once it found just get  top offset and scroll to that item. This scrolling works fine, so you can avoid that. I put that in code for a better view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of requesting individual pages change your AJAX request to include the name/ID of the item you are searching for and current page number.

Have the server side code respond to this with a list of pages/items between your current page and the target page (the page containing the target item).

Once the response is received animate the received pages as per client request (the same way you are doing it now).

The difference here is that you are making one asynchronous request and you receive all the data you need. From there on you can animate in any way you want using CSS and JS.

Another benefit of this approach is that you can properly handle connection errors, request exceptions and other exceptions that might result when the target item is not found.